# Faces not getting detected from Kinect Feed

Tags: c#, kinect, emgucv, face-detection

Below is the code for a method which I am using for detecting faces from Kinect Feed and then setting the pixels from the face into a new image. . It is triggered by a Gesture which is done by `GestureFlag` . The `Detect` method which I am calling from the `FaceDetection` class is taken from the EMGU CV sample.

```
 public string Detect(WriteableBitmap colorBitmap, int GestureFlag)
    {
        if(GestureFlag!=0)
        {
            List<Rectangle> faces = new List<Rectangle>();               
            Bitmap bitface = BitmapFromSource(colorBitmap);
            Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bitface);
            FaceDetection.Detect(image, "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml",faces);
             Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\rama\Downloads\kinect-2-background-removal-master\KinectBackgroundRemoval\Assets\emptyimage.png");
            img = ResizeImage(img, 1540, 1980);
            int high = image.Height;
            int width = image.Width;                
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < high; j++)
                {
                    Bgr pixel = image[j,i];
                    System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(j,i);                    
                        if (faces[0].Contains(p) && i<1540 && j<1980)
                        {
                            img.SetPixel(i, j, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, (int)pixel.Blue, (int)pixel.Green,(int) pixel.Red));
                        }                   
                }
            }
            count++;
            key = count.ToString() + "rich.jpg";
            image.Save(@"C:\Users\rama\Downloads\kinect-2-background-removal-master\KinectBackgroundRemoval\Assets\"+key);
            img.Save(@"C:\Users\rama\Downloads\kinect-2-background-removal-master\KinectBackgroundRemoval\"+key);
            bool status = UploadToS3("nitish2", key, @"C:\Users\rama\Downloads\kinect-2-background-removal-master\KinectBackgroundRemoval\"+key);
            var FBClient = new FacebookClient();
            var UploadToFacebook = new FacebookUpload(FBClient, key);
            UploadToFacebook.Show();
            GestureFlag = 0;                      
         }
        return key;
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is that an entirely different set of pixels gets printed on the new image which I'm saving.

Basically i think that the problem is here:

```
FaceDetection.Detect(image, "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml",faces);
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < high; j++)
                {
                    Bgr pixel = image[j,i];
                    System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(j,i);
                    if (faces[0].Contains(p) && i<1540 && j<1980)
                        {
                            img.SetPixel(i, j, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, (int)pixel.Blue, (int)pixel.Green,(int) pixel.Red));
                        }

                 }
            }
```

So can someone please point out where I'm going wrong?
Thank you very much.

EDITS : I've tried putting flags like `faces[0]!=null` which should take care of whether `FaceDetection.Detect` is actually returning anything but still I'm getting the same result.

I've also tried saving the `ColorBitmap` and testing it against the EMGU CV sample and it detects the faces in the image easily.

EDIT 2: So I've cross checked the co-ordinates of the rectangle which is being printed with the co-ordinates of the face being detected and the values of the `Rectangle()` being populated. They turn out to be almost same as far as I can see. So no luck there.

I don't know what else I can try for debugging.

If someone could point that out that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it to work finally.

The problem was the `Point[j,i]` which should have been `Point[i,j]` . Also my `FaceDetection` method proved to be a little erratic and I had to fix that too to finally properly debug my code.